# How to understand AnyLogic source generated pattern?

Tags: anylogic

whats the meaning of setting up a new source element from the PML library with the following parameters?

- Arrivals defined by: **interarrival time**;
- Interarrival time: **exponential(1) - minutes**;

how often it generates new agents? I'have read the documentation but I don't understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're interested in all the statistical part of the distribution so I'll keep it simple.

When you have an exponential distribution *exponential(lambda)* you have the following:

- Expected value E(X) (**mean**): 1/lambda
- Variance V(X): 1/lambda^2
- Standard Deviation = sqrt(Variance)

Therefore the standard deviation is the same as the mean.

Those are the basics about the exponential distribution. 
In your case, you are using an exponential distribution with lambda = 1 which means the mean will also be 1 so, in average, your interarrival time will be 1.

If you had lambda = 2 your average interarrival time would be 1/2 = 0.5.

Hope that helps

Comment: So, if I understood correctly calling "exponential(4)" with simulation time is setting up to "minute" the source block on average will generate 1 agent every 15 seconds?

Comment: yes it will. If you want to confirm that in anylogic just run the model for a large amount of time and measure the average time between arrivals.

Comment: Thanks for your time